# Where can i find my data that i entered in my android app through AWS Cognito

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, synchronization, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

i have developed a android application, in which i am using AWS Cognito for sync purpose.I have downloaded the sample code from the following official [link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples#help). And in my app I can able to enter the data.
Now my question is, where these data are get stored, where can i access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today Cognito launched a feature to browse and edit the data in sync store using console. You can refer to :[Sync Store Access](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cognito-update-sync-store-access-improved-console-more/)

Answer (score 1):

Using developer credentials you can call the ListRecords api using one of the low-level SDKs of Cognito or the command line to get access to data for any identity, but this functionality is not in the console at this time.